# Ubuntu cannot detect my Logitech Wireless m510 mouse?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wubi

I have my mouse plugged in but it doesn't have drivers so it doesn't work.

How do I find the drivers? Please give me a link or tell me how to detect them from Ubuntu Software?

Comment: The M510 uses the Logitech Unifying receiver - is it plugged into a working USB port and detected by the system?

Answer (score 1):

Download HID for your mouse and keyboard and version of Ubuntu [**here**](http://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint/download.html).
Installation And Un-installation Instruction [**here**](http://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint/support/installing-hidpoint.html).

You can also try this before downloading from the above link.

Open your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter in:

```
lsusb
```

Comment: Does this work for 12.04?